# How to call tooltip in joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In default.php

```
JHTML::_('behavior.tooltip');
<a href="#">
<?php echo JHTML::tooltip('test test test', 'title', '', 'title');?></a>
```

But it can't show tooltip ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Please go through this link,this may helpful to you

[Click](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1492489)

Answer (score 8):

A tooltip for text is done as so:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
echo JHtml::tooltip('Tooltip Text', 'Tooltip Title', '', 'Text to be hovered over');
```

and a tooltip for an image, can be done like so:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::tooltip('Tooltip Text', 'Tooltip title', 'tooltip.png', '', '', false);
```

For more information, please read the [Joomla Docs on Tooltips](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_add_tooltips_to_your_Joomla!_website):